# Using any / all in an SQL query - doesn't seem to work in any app I've tried

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've tried SQLiteSpy, SQLite Administrator and SQLite Expert Personal and none of the apps seem to work with these keywords.  I'm following along the Intro to Databases on Coursera and the professor is using Database Master for querying.  I'm unable to use the app as I keep getting errors about illegal characters in the path so I gave up on it. Plus it's not a free app.

In all cases, the code blocks below will error out around "select".  If I remove the keywords, the query will run but return the wrong results.  I'm not sure why it isn't working.  Anyone know?

Anyway, this is an example of code...

```
select cName  
from College C1  
where enrollment > all ( select enrollment from College C2 where C2.cName <> C1.cName);
```

Another example using all...

```
select College.cName, state, GPA
from College, Apply, Student
where College.cName = Apply.cName
  and Apply.sID = Student.sID      
  and GPA >= all     
          (select GPA from Student, Apply              
           where Student.sID = Apply.sID               
           and   Apply.cName = College.cName);
```

And a final example using any...

```
select cName  
from College S1  
where not enrollment <= any (select enrollment from College S2 where S2.cName <> S1.cName);
```

Comment: [I don't see any indication that SQLite supports these](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#in_op). Why not download a more full featured DBMS such as PostgreSQL or Express edition of SQL Server or Oracle?

Comment: As @Martin points out - the underlying engine doesn't support these. You *could* re-write your queries to achieve the same results, but that's definitely not the way you want to be doing doing this as they may well be other functions that are assumed to be builtin and I imagine it'd inhibit productive learning. I'd go with a database such as PostgreSQL. So, I think your actual answer is - not much you can do with your current code and setup...

Comment: Thanks guys! I didn't even think to switch dbms.  I'm going to try out SQL Server Express since we do use SQL Server at work anyway.

And yeah, I thought about rewritting as I go along but the professor kept showing queries that I kept getting errors with which was frustrating me.

Comment: I ended up using PostgreSQL and it works!  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't find `any` and `all` to really be useful in understanding queries.  You can rewrite your queries as:

```
select cName  
from College C1  
where enrollment > ( select max(enrollment) from College C2 where C2.cName <> C1.cName);

select College.cName, state, GPA
from College join
     Apply
     on College.cName = Apply.cName join
     Student
     on Apply.sID = Student.sID 
where GPA >= (select max(GPA)
              from Student join
                   Apply              
                   on Student.sID = Apply.sID               
              where Apply.cName = College.cName
             );
```

The last one is a bit harder to understand.  I think it is:

```
select cName  
from College S1  
where enrollment > (select max(enrollment) from College S2 where S2.cName <> S1.cName);
```

As a bonus, I also changed the queries to use explicit `join` syntax rather than implicit joins in the `where` clause.

Comment: Thanks for this!  Appreciate knowing other ways of handling the queries.